# Wordpress, проблема с контактной формой

Tags: javascript, wordpress, ajax, contact-form7

1. Вот тут обычная рабочая форма:
   [www.astlaw.co.il/?test_form=1](https://www.astlaw.co.il/?test_form=1)
2. А тут форма которая подгружается динамично, через AJAX:
   [www.astlaw.co.il/?test_form=2](https://www.astlaw.co.il/?test_form=2)

Во втором случае в процессе события submit что то идет не так и страница перезагружается.
Письмо админу приходит, но не работает ни валидация ни событие "wpcf7mailsent".

После перезагрузки страницы нет возможности проверить консоль.

Вот код подгрузки формы:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/?test_form=2&ajax=1",
    context: document.body
  }).done(function(data) {
    $(".contact-form-wr").html(data);
    //wpcf7.initForm($(".contact-form-wr form"));
  });
});
```

Пробовал после подгрузки применять wpcf7.initForm().

Получаю ошибку "Uncaught TypeError: wpcf7.initForm is not a function".

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 2):

у вас же написано что такой функции нет...
начиная с 5 версии cf7 для инициализации формы нужно использовать метод `init`.
В вашем случае это будет вот так:

```
wpcf7.init( document.querySelector( '.contact-form-wr form' ) )
```